# comparação de array de char retorna false mesmo para char[] iguais - C

Tags: c, struct, comparação

sou iniciante em C, estou fazendo uma atividade da faculdade e tentando comparar um dado obtido via scanf com um dado salvo em um array de registro que crei mas mesmo inserindo o mesmo valor, sempre retorna falso, independente do método de comparação.

meu struct:

```
// Struct Veiculo
typedef struct
{
  char marca[50];
  char modelo[50];
  int anofab;
  Placa placa;
} Veiculo;

// Struct Veiculos (Container para veículo)
typedef struct
{
  int count;
  Veiculo v[10];
} Veiculos;
```

Onde eu obtenho o valor:

```
Veiculos frota;
char temp[50];
printf("Insira o modelo: ");
scanf("%s", &temp);
filtrarmodelo(&frota, temp);
```

Onde eu faço a comparação:

```
void filtrarmodelo(Veiculos *frota, char modelo[50])
{
  printf("\n\n---------- [LISTANDO MODELO SELECIONADO] ----------\n\n");

  // Se não houver veículos, cai aqui
  if (frota->count == 0)
  {
    printf("\nNada para mostrar aqui :(\n\n");
  }

  else
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < frota->count; i++)
    {
      // Compara o modelo inserido com os modelos salvos anteriormente
      if (strcmp(frota->v[i].modelo, modelo))
      {
        printf("%s %s, %d. Placa %s-%s\n\n",
               frota->v[i].marca,
               frota->v[i].modelo,
               frota->v[i].anofab,
               frota->v[i].placa.letras,
               frota->v[i].placa.numeros);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("\nNenhum modelo encontrado :(\n\n");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A saída que eu obtive na última execução foi que nenhum modelo foi encontrado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que a função `strcmp()` retorna o valor 0 caso as duas strings sejam iguais, e em C, o valor `0` representa o `false`, então a forma certa de comparar é: `strcmp(stringA, stringB) == 0`, esse código retorna `true` caso as duas `strings` sejam iguais.
*Código funcionando, adaptado, pois faltou coisas na pergunta, com um exemplo de teste:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char marca[50];
    char modelo[50];
    int anofab;
} Veiculo;

typedef struct
{
    int count;
    Veiculo v[10];
} Veiculos;


void filtrarmodelo(Veiculos *frota, char modelo[50])
{
    printf("\n\n---------- [LISTANDO MODELO SELECIONADO] ----------\n\n");
    
    if (frota->count == 0)
    {
        printf("Nao ha carros na frota.\n");
        return;
    }
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < frota->count; i++)
        {
            printf("%s - %s\n", frota->v[i].modelo, modelo);
            if (strcmp(frota->v[i].modelo, modelo) == 0)
                printf
                (   
                    "%s %s, %d.\n",
                    frota->v[i].marca,
                    frota->v[i].modelo,
                    frota->v[i].anofab
                );
            else
                printf("Nenhum modelo encontrado.\n");
        }
}
int main()
{
    Veiculos frota;
    frota.count = 1;
    Veiculo veiculoNovo = { .marca = "Ab",  .modelo = "Cd", .anofab = 2022};
    frota.v[0] = veiculoNovo;

    char temp[50];
    printf("Insira o modelo: ");
    scanf("%s", temp);
    filtrarmodelo(&frota, temp);

    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

---

*Input*
`Cd`

---

*Output*

```
---------- [LISTANDO MODELO SELECIONADO] ----------

Cd - Cd
Ab Cd, 2022.
```

Comment: caramba, muito obrigado amigo. agora se puder me explicar uma coisa, porque minha pergunta teve dois votos negativos? eu não uso muito o stack overflow então ainda não peguei bem a dinâmica do site. sobre a falta de informações eu pensei que ficaria muito código e bagunçaria a questão por isso coloquei somente a parte envolvida no problema. mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Para melhorar sua perguntar você precisar ler o texto deste [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel?cb=1). E também tem o texto ao lado na [pagina de criação de perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).